# Getting data (text, ...) what user says

Tags: google-home

Is it possible to get the text of what a user says to Google home ? I couldn't find any way how to do that.
I have an API that can process language as a text. If that's not possible, is it possible to get what users says. I could then use speech recognition to get the text.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the RawInputs portion of the conversation API.

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/conversation#RawInputs